# How to align points on the outer edges of polygon for thicker border in svg?

Tags: svg, d3.js, stroke

My question is:

I have a polygon which is drawn by taking some points and I am showing the points on the edges/outline of polygon. When I increase the stroke-width for the polygon the points getting aligned in the center of the outline. How do we achieve the points alignment on the outside of the edge/border?

**Actual how it come is like below picture, the points are center aligned across the border/stroke**

[image]

working area link for this is
`https://codepen.io/jinata92/pen/JjKZeqE`

**I am looking for a solution like as below picture, The points should be aligned on the outer edges of border/stroke**

[image]

```js
var height = 100,
  width = 100;
var polygon;
var arrVertexes = [
  [6, 6],
  [94, 6],
  [94, 94],
  [6, 94]
];

var svg, gContainer;

function config() {
  svg = d3
    .select(".main")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("viewBox", `0 0 ${width} ${height}`);

  gContainer = svg.select("g");
}

function drawPolygon() {
  polygon = gContainer
    .append("polygon")
    .attr("points", arrVertexes)
    .attr("class", "segment");
}

function drawCircle() {
  gContainer
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(arrVertexes)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "vertex")
    .classed("handle", true)
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return d[0];
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return d[1];
    })
    .attr("r", 4);
}

config();
drawPolygon();
drawCircle();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: visible;
}

.resize-div {
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
}

.polygon {
  stroke: yellow;
  fill: transparent;
}

.vertex,
.dot {
  fill: black;
  stroke: none;
}

.segment {
  stroke-width: 30;
  stroke: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<div style="width:100px;height:100px; left: 400px;
                    top:50px;" class="resize-div">
  <svg class="main" height="100%" width="100%">
    <g class="polygon"></g>

  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stroke-width is always applied to both sides, so the centre of the line is still at the required place. But there are some workarounds. One is to just draw the shape, but also apply a [clip path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath) equal to the element, but *without* the stroke-width:

```js
var height = 100,
  width = 100;
var polygon;
var arrVertexes = [
  [6, 6],
  [94, 6],
  [94, 94],
  [6, 94]
];

var svg, gContainer;

function config() {
  svg = d3
    .select(".main")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("viewBox", `0 0 ${width} ${height}`);

  gContainer = svg.select("g");
}

function drawPolygon() {
  polygon = gContainer
    .append("polygon")
    .attr("clip-path", "url('#my-clip-path')")
    .attr("points", arrVertexes)
    .attr("class", "segment");

  // Append a clip path
  svg.append("defs")
    .append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "my-clip-path")
    .append("polygon")
    .attr("points", arrVertexes)
    .attr("class", "segment");
}

function drawCircle() {
  gContainer
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(arrVertexes)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "vertex")
    .classed("handle", true)
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return d[0];
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return d[1];
    })
    .attr("r", 4);
}

config();
drawPolygon();
drawCircle();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: visible;
}

.resize-div {
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
}

.polygon {
  stroke: yellow;
  fill: transparent;
}

.vertex,
.dot {
  fill: black;
  stroke: none;
}

.segment {
  stroke-width: 30;
  stroke: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<div style="width:100px;height:100px; left: 400px;
                    top:50px;" class="resize-div">
  <svg class="main" height="100%" width="100%">
    <g class="polygon"></g>

  </svg>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could draw a polygon on top of the other, but inwards a little bit. Use the bounding box to calculate the centre of the outer polygon, and move the coordinates of the inner polygon inwards by some number of pixels:

```js
var height = 100,
  width = 100;
var polygon;
var arrVertexes = [
  [6, 6],
  [94, 6],
  [94, 94],
  [6, 94]
];

var svg, gContainer;

function config() {
  svg = d3
    .select(".main")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("viewBox", `0 0 ${width} ${height}`);

  gContainer = svg.select("g");
}

function drawPolygon() {
  polygon = gContainer
    .append("polygon")
    .attr("points", arrVertexes)
    .attr("class", "segment-border");

  // Get the bounding box so you can calculate the centre
  const boundingBox = polygon.node().getBBox();
  const centre = {
    x: boundingBox.x + boundingBox.width / 2,
    y: boundingBox.y + boundingBox.height / 2,
  };

  const innerVertexes = arrVertexes.map(d => [
    d[0] < centre.x ? d[0] + 15 : d[0] - 15,
    d[1] < centre.y ? d[1] + 15 : d[1] - 15,
  ]);
  polygon = gContainer
    .append("polygon")
    .attr("points", innerVertexes)
    .attr("class", "segment");
}

function drawCircle() {
  gContainer
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(arrVertexes)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "vertex")
    .classed("handle", true)
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return d[0];
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return d[1];
    })
    .attr("r", 4);
}

config();
drawPolygon();
drawCircle();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: visible;
}

.resize-div {
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
}

.polygon {
  stroke: yellow;
  fill: transparent;
}

.vertex,
.dot {
  fill: black;
  stroke: none;
}

.segment-border {
  fill: yellow;
}

.segment {
  fill: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<div style="width:100px;height:100px; left: 400px;
                    top:50px;" class="resize-div">
  <svg class="main" height="100%" width="100%">
    <g class="polygon"></g>

  </svg>
</div>
```