# d3 polygon and trash icon on edge

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to render polygon shapes in d3.js – but on the edge of each polygon provide a trash icon so the polygon itself can be removed.

Then keep a track of remaining polygons.

1. how do you append circles/trash icons to the edge of polygon boundaries – near the top of the shape?
2. how do you make/render trash icons – a png image or another svg shape that gets attached

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/o9t6ardh/

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", 1000)
      .attr("height", 667);

    var scaleX = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([-30, 30])
      .range([0, 600]);

    var scaleY = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, 50])
      .range([500, 0]);

    var data = [{
        "code": "BR23",
        "points": "405,100.5625,331,108.5625,300,120.5625,290,141.5625,283,158.5625,278,171.5625,289,209.5625,304,231.5625,332,255.5625,351,264.5625,383,268.5625,400,266.5625,440,266.5625,462,266.5625,510,257.5625,522,230.5625,530,210.5625,534,183.5625,524,163.5625,512,148.5625,490,134.5625,462,124.5625"
      },
      {
        "code": "FR23",
        "points": "702,164.5625,594,250.5625,689,324.5625,749,261.5625,770,206.5625"
      }
    ];

    vis.selectAll("polygon")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("polygon")
      .attr("points", function(d, i) {
        return d.points
      })
      .attr("fill", "transparent")
      .attr("stroke", "red")
      .attr("stroke-width", 2)
      .style("stroke-dasharray", ("15, 15")) // <== This line here!!
      .on("click", function(d, i) {
        console.log("d", d);
        d3.select(this).style("fill", "blue");
      });


    vis.append('circle')
      .attr('cx', 110)
      .attr('cy', 110)
      .attr('r', 20)
      .attr('stroke', 'black')
      .attr('fill', '#69a3b2')
      .on("click", function(d, i) {
        console.log("d", d);
      });


  });
</script>
```

do you need to work out boundaries of the shapes?

[How to align points on the outer edges of polygon for thicker border in svg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65002012/how-to-align-points-on-the-outer-edges-of-polygon-for-thicker-border-in-svg)

latest jsfiddles

http://jsfiddle.net/n6bdavxk/

http://jsfiddle.net/5kqLftzy/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Approach 1: Get polygon bounding box

As already mentioned, you need to calculate the bounding box coordinates for each polygon in your data set.

It's probably more convenient to add these coordinates directly to your data array - so you can use this data within your D3 function chain for positioning.

Here's a simple helper function:

```
function getDataBounds(data) {
    data.forEach((item, i) => {
      let coords = item.points.split(",").map((val) => {
        return +val;
      });
      let xAll = coords.filter((coord, i) => i % 2 === 0);
      let yAll = coords.filter((coord, i) => i % 2 !== 0);
      let xMin = Math.min(...xAll);
      let xMax = Math.max(...xAll);
      let yMin = Math.min(...yAll);
      let yMax = Math.max(...yAll);
      let bb = {
        x: xMin,
        y: yMin,
        cx: xMin + (xMax - xMin) / 2,
        cy: yMin + (yMax - yMin) / 2,
        top: yMin,
        bottom: yMax,
        right: xMax,
        left: xMin,
        width: xMax - xMin,
        height: yMax - yMin
      };
      data[i].bb = bb;
    });
    return data;
  }
```

It loops through all polygon points and calculates the bounding box according to x and y extrema.

The centroid coordinates would be:

```
    cx: xMin + (xMax - xMin) / 2,
    cy: yMin + (yMax - yMin) / 2,
```

If your polygons are already **appended to the DOM**, you could also use `getBBox()`.

#### Create trash button icon

I'd recommend to design an icon in an editor like inkscape including a background circle. This way you don't need to append multiple elements (imho,  selecting parent nodes in d3 can be a bit ["unintuitive"](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/issues/177) ...).

```css
body{
  background:#ccc;
}

svg{
  color:red
}
```

```html
<h3>Icon Design</h3>
<svg  viewBox="0 0 640 720" width="40" height="40">
  <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fill="white"/>
  <path d="M152.6 576v-378h-24.6v-36h112.8v-18h158.4v18h112.8v36h-24.6v378h-334.8zm36-36h262.8v-342h-262.8v342zm63.6-51.6h36v-239.4h-36v239.4zm99.6 0h36v-239.4h-36v239.4zm-163.2-290.4v342v-342z" fill="currentColor"/>
</svg>


<h3>Reusable Icon asset</h3>
<svg width="40" height="40">><use href="#icnTrash"/></svg>
<svg width="40" height="40">><use href="#icnTrash" style="color:green"/></svg>

<!-- hidden icon asset -->
<svg style="width:0; height:0">
  <symbol id="icnTrash" viewBox="0 0 640 720">
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fill="white" />
    <path d="M152.6 576v-378h-24.6v-36h112.8v-18h158.4v18h112.8v36h-24.6v378h-334.8zm36-36h262.8v-342h-262.8v342zm63.6-51.6h36v-239.4h-36v239.4zm99.6 0h36v-239.4h-36v239.4zm-163.2-290.4v342v-342z" fill="currentColor" />
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

### Example

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var vis = d3
    .select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 1000)
    .attr("height", 667);

  var scaleX = d3.scale.linear().domain([-30, 30]).range([0, 600]);
  var scaleY = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 50]).range([500, 0]);

  var data = [
    {
      code: "BR23",
      points:
        "405,100.5625,331,108.5625,300,120.5625,290,141.5625,283,158.5625,278,171.5625,289,209.5625,304,231.5625,332,255.5625,351,264.5625,383,268.5625,400,266.5625,440,266.5625,462,266.5625,510,257.5625,522,230.5625,530,210.5625,534,183.5625,524,163.5625,512,148.5625,490,134.5625,462,124.5625"
    },
    {
      code: "FR23",
      points: "702,164.5625,594,250.5625,689,324.5625,749,261.5625,770,206.5625"
    }
  ];

  /**
   * calculate bounds for polygons
   *
   */
  function getDataBounds(data) {
    data.forEach((item, i) => {
      let coords = item.points.split(",").map((val) => {
        return +val;
      });
      let xAll = coords.filter((coord, i) => i % 2 === 0);
      let yAll = coords.filter((coord, i) => i % 2 !== 0);
      let xMin = Math.min(...xAll);
      let xMax = Math.max(...xAll);
      let yMin = Math.min(...yAll);
      let yMax = Math.max(...yAll);
      let bb = {
        x: xMin,
        y: yMin,
        cx: xMin + (xMax - xMin) / 2,
        cy: yMin + (yMax - yMin) / 2,
        top: yMin,
        bottom: yMax,
        right: xMax,
        left: xMin,
        width: xMax - xMin,
        height: yMax - yMin
      };
      data[i].bb = bb;
    });
    return data;
  }

  // add boundaries to data array
  data = getDataBounds(data);
  let iconWidth = 40;
  let iconHeight = 40;

  vis
    .selectAll("polygon")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("polygon")
    .attr("id", (d, i) => {
      return "polygon" + d.code;
    })
    .attr("points", function (d, i) {
      return d.points;
    })
    .attr("fill", "transparent")
    .attr("stroke", "red")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .style("stroke-dasharray", "15, 15") // <== This line here!!
    .on("click", function (d, i) {
      d3.select(this).node().classList.toggle("selected");
      //let btn = document.getElementById("btnPoly-" + d.code);
      //btn.classList.toggle("hidden");
    });

  // add circles
  vis
    .selectAll("use")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("use")
    .attr("class", "btnTrash")
    .attr("id", function (d, i) {
      return "btnPoly-" + d.code;
    })
    .attr("width", iconWidth)
    .attr("height", iconHeight)
    .attr("href", "#icnTrash")
    .attr("x", function (d, i) {
      return d.bb.cx - iconWidth / 2;
    })
    .attr("y", function (d, i) {
      return d.bb.top - iconHeight / 2 - 20;
    })
    .on("click", (d, i) => {
      let poly = document.getElementById("polygon" + d.code);
      let btnTrash = document.getElementById("btnPoly-" + d.code);
      btnTrash.remove();
      poly.remove();
    });
});
```

```css
body{
  background:#ccc;
}

.btnTrash{
  color:red
}

.hidden{
  opacity:0
}

.selected{
  stroke: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<!-- hidden icon asset -->
<svg style="width:0; height:0">
  <symbol id="icnTrash" viewBox="0 0 640 720">
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fill="white" />
    <path d="M152.6 576v-378h-24.6v-36h112.8v-18h158.4v18h112.8v36h-24.6v378h-334.8zm36-36h262.8v-342h-262.8v342zm63.6-51.6h36v-239.4h-36v239.4zm99.6 0h36v-239.4h-36v239.4zm-163.2-290.4v342v-342z" fill="currentColor" />
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

### Approach 2: get topmost point on polygon outline

Similar to the first approach, we're updating the initial data object.
This time we're searching the top most point on the polygon's outline.

We get this point by comparing the y values of each polygon vertice.

```
  function getTopMostPoint(data) {
    data.forEach((item, i) => {
      let points = item.points.split(',');
      let topY = 999999;
      let pTop = {}
      for(let p=0; p<points.length; p+=2){
        let pt = {x:+points[p], y:+points[p+1]}
        if(pt.y<topY){
          pTop = pt;
          topY = pt.y;
        }
      }
      data[i].anchor = {
        x: pTop.x,
        y: pTop.y
      };
     
    });
    return data;
  }
```

```js
  
  var data = [
    {
      code: "BR23",
      points:
        "405,100.5625,331,108.5625,300,120.5625,290,141.5625,283,158.5625,278,171.5625,289,209.5625,304,231.5625,332,255.5625,351,264.5625,383,268.5625,400,266.5625,440,266.5625,462,266.5625,510,257.5625,522,230.5625,530,210.5625,534,183.5625,524,163.5625,512,148.5625,490,134.5625,462,124.5625"
    },
    {
      code: "FR23",
      points: "702,164.5625,594,250.5625,689,324.5625,749,261.5625,770,206.5625"
    }
  ];

/**
   * calculate anchor for polygons
   * find topmost point on polygon outline
   *
   */
  function getTopMostPoint(data) {
    data.forEach((item, i) => {
      let points = item.points.split(',');
      let topY = 999999;
      let pTop = {}
      for(let p=0; p<points.length; p+=2){
        let pt = {x:+points[p], y:+points[p+1]}
        if(pt.y<topY){
          pTop = pt;
          topY = pt.y;
        }
      }
      data[i].anchor = {
        x: pTop.x,
        y: pTop.y
      };
     
    });
    return data;
  }



$(document).ready(function () {
  var vis = d3
    .select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 1000)
    .attr("height", 667);

  var scaleX = d3.scale.linear().domain([-30, 30]).range([0, 600]);
  var scaleY = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 50]).range([500, 0]);

  // get topmost point
  data = getTopMostPoint(data);

  let iconWidth = 40;
  let iconHeight = 40;

  vis
    .selectAll("polygon")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("polygon")
    .attr("id", (d, i) => {
      return "polygon" + d.code;
    })
    .attr("points", function (d, i) {
      return d.points;
    })
    .attr("fill", "transparent")
    .attr("stroke", "red")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .style("stroke-dasharray", "15, 15") // <== This line here!!
    .on("click", function (d, i) {
      d3.select(this).node().classList.toggle("selected");
      //let btn = document.getElementById("btnPoly-" + d.code);
      //btn.classList.toggle("hidden");
    });

  // add circles
  vis
    .selectAll("use")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("use")
    .attr("class", "btnTrash")
    .attr("id", function (d, i) {
      return "btnPoly-" + d.code;
    })
    .attr("width", iconWidth)
    .attr("height", iconHeight)
    .attr("href", "#icnTrash")
    .attr("x", function (d, i) {
      return d.anchor.x - iconWidth / 2;
    })
    .attr("y", function (d, i) {
      return d.anchor.y - iconHeight / 2 - 20;
    })
    .on("click", (d, i) => {
      let poly = document.getElementById("polygon" + d.code);
      let btnTrash = document.getElementById("btnPoly-" + d.code);
      btnTrash.remove();
      poly.remove();
    });
});
```

```css
body{
  background:#ccc;
}

.btnTrash{
  color:red
}

.selected{
  stroke: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<!-- hidden icon asset -->
<svg style="width:0; height:0">
  <symbol id="icnTrash" viewBox="0 0 640 720">
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fill="white" />
    <path d="M152.6 576v-378h-24.6v-36h112.8v-18h158.4v18h112.8v36h-24.6v378h-334.8zm36-36h262.8v-342h-262.8v342zm63.6-51.6h36v-239.4h-36v239.4zm99.6 0h36v-239.4h-36v239.4zm-163.2-290.4v342v-342z" fill="currentColor" />
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

Comment: your code doesnt render a trash box on the boundary of the polygons?

Comment: Not sure ... they will only render when clicking the polygon. You could also display them on initial rendering. Just remove the opacity css rule.

Comment: yeah - they should be on initial rendering -  I think - and then if the user clicks the trash can it deletes the polygon -- I dont think there is a css change to fill blue in the polygon itself -as there would be an image under the d3.js

Comment: Have a look at the second example based on `getPointAtLength`. This example will find anchors that are always on the polygons outline. Buttons are always visible. I've added a sample selected class thats toggled when clicking the polygon.

Comment: @The Old County: stupid me! We don't need getPointAtLength() but can use the already known polygon vertices – which is way faster! Check the updated example. If you need the (clunky) previous example see this [codepen](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/OJBGqpY)

Comment: Able to create another variant where the trashcan white backgrounds are more "location icon" like tear drop shaped as per the original reference/design

Comment: @The Old County:  Why should I add a jsfiddle link, if there are running snippets? (always preferable).

Comment: Here are the jsfiddle links again -- http://jsfiddle.net/n6bdavxk/ -- http://jsfiddle.net/5kqLftzy/1/

Comment: so out of the two approaches - what would you consider is the best and why -- I wasn't really sure what the difference is - one uses the border calculation?

Comment: @The Old County: From a design perspective I'd prefer the second approach since the icon will always "touch" the polygon's outline.  The first approach could be handy if you need to position the delete button **centered**. I appologize for being a bit harsh about jsfiddle. It's just better to include examples within SO snippets since you might delete external fiddles/or codepens etc. This is especially true if the answering user haven't created this fiddle (Besides, I think jsfiddle should overhaul its UI - responsive view kinda s*cks =)

Comment: Its ok - I know it sucks -the snippets are ok - but I like make a jsfiddle and try and keep some online free link around - as well as play locally. I just didnt want to have to be confined to a specific row as the only way to see it on a blog post. You have precious knowledge lol.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first two scripts and use document.querySelectorAll, then it works.

Comment: that doesnt explain how to SET another svg or image object to the boundary of the polygon at the top

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: **d3.js and jquery are required** by the app's script to run. Deleting these script resources will break the script. Besides, there is no issue related to selections. Please revise your answer.

Comment: No, you have not to use jquery, then it works. I've tested your code.

Comment: Fair enough, but what about D3? And where would you use querySelectorAll()? How does it solve the OPs problem positioning the icons? Please provide a running example.